# I can not use className here in my organization, and it is not working with tw

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I am trying to create tooltip here by using Tailwind css and displaying it on Pebble SVG

```
<div className="relative items-center group">
    <span tw="flex items-center gap-1">
           Payment method
        <Pebble />
    </span>
    <div tw="bottom-0 flex flex-col items-center hidden group-hover:flex">
        <span tw="relative p-2 text-sm text-inkWhite-100 bg-inkBlack-100">
            If you'd like to change your payment method, go to section.
        </span>
        <div tw="w-3 h-3 -mt-2 rotate-45 bg-black"></div>
    </div
```

Any other way around for it?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot use className here in my organization"? Because a. that's absurd and b. you use className in your code example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.